# Are there any web frameworks for JVM with data binding checked at compilation time?

Tags: java, data-binding, jvm, web-frameworks

Usually when you bind some property to some element in www page, you will know about typo when testing.

I am looking for web framework which, at compile time would give me an error, that I made error in binding ("property not found" or something similar) and assuming my IDE has valid refactorization mechanism, that renaming property would also affect the binding (and vice-versa), or in other words, that renaming would not result in broken code.

**Is there such framework for JVM?**

*I am new to JVM world so I don't know the features of the JVM frameworks (at all, not just this feature I ask for).*

Comment: JSP development in Eclipse can do this.

Comment: Wow, great news (only pity it is done for probably the most heavy weight framework ;-D). Could you post your comment as the answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP development in Eclipse can do this

Comment: [*Vaadin Framework*](http://www.Vaadin.com/) is so much easier and more productive, with a sophisticated yet easy-to-use data binding facility and integrated Bean Validation support. See [the Answer by jreznot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48167110/642706).

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented [static-mustache library](https://github.com/sviperll/static-mustache) to provide a type-safe template engine based on mustache syntax.

It checks both syntax errors and type-errors (like missing property) at compile-time. It requires zero build configuration as it's a standard annotation processor.

Templates remain pure mustache templates with all type-information extracted from normal Java-class used for rendering.

Answer (score 1):

## Vaadin Framework

[Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) 8+ supports this kind of binding with Java lambda expressions.

There is a special [`Binder`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.2/8.2.0/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/Binder.html) class:

```
Binder<Person> binder = new Binder<>();
TextField titleField = new TextField();

// Start by defining the Field instance to use
binder.forField(titleField)
  // Finalize by doing the actual binding to the Person class
  .bind(
    // Callback that loads the title from a person instance
    Person::getTitle,
    // Callback that saves the title in a person instance
    Person::setTitle));
```

See docs for details: https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/datamodel/datamodel-forms.html